# I need to find a way to reset "count" after completing one test sample with out reseting count during the recursive function

Tags: python, function, nested-function

This is what my code needs to do:

Write a function, `persistence`, that takes in a positive parameter `num` and returns its multiplicative persistence, which is the number of times you must multiply the digits in `num` until you reach a single digit.

```
Test.it("Basic tests")
Test.assert_equals(persistence(39), 3)
Test.assert_equals(persistence(4), 0)
Test.assert_equals(persistence(25), 2)
Test.assert_equals(persistence(999), 4)
```

This is a Codewars challenge. I can test assert samples individually but not all at once. Codewars need to be able to run all its test samples all at once. I need to find a way to reset `count` after completing one test sample without resetting `count` during the recursive function.

```
count = 0
def persistence(n):
    # your code
    global count

    #def recursion(result):
    number_str = str(n)

    ints = [int(i) for i in number_str if i != '0']
    result = 1
    for j in ints:
        result = result * j
    if result >= 10:
        print(ints,"\n\n------------------------------------------")
        count += 1
        print(count)
        print(result)

        return persistence(result)
    else:
        if count > 0:
            count += 1
            return count 
        else:
            return count
```

This is the code I came up with. I need my function to run all four tests at once. My function can recursively render one test at a time, but not all tests at once. I need to figure out how to reset `count` after each test sample assertion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recursive function should not need a global variable. You can pass `counts` as a parameter instead, with a default value to handle the public API case where it's not passed in:

```
def persistence(n, count=0):
    ...
    # everything is the same up until the recursion
    return persistence(result, count)
```

You could simplify the code a bit by just doing inline addition rather than using `+=` statements on `count`, if you want, but it won't change the behavior of the code.

I'd also note that since your function is tail recursive, you could pretty easily replace the recursion with a loop. I think something like this might do it:

```
def persistance(n):
    count = 0
    while n >= 10:
        count += 1
        ints = [int(i) for i in str(n) if i != '0']
        n = 1
        for i in ints:
            n *= i
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass along the count down the recursive call, like this:

```
count = 0
def persistence(n, count):

    # ..
    # update count
    # ..

    return persistence(result, count)

    # ...
    return count
```

or if you cant change the signature of `persistance`, use an auxiliary function, which is very common in functional programming.

```
def persistance(n):
    return persistance_aux(n, 0)

def persistance_aux(n, count):
    # ....
```